Detached process closes when exiting KMP Windows App
I'm developing a Kotlin desktop application using Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) Compose. The application needs to launch a separate Windows cmd process upon startup. However, I'm encountering an issue where the cmd window closes immediately after the application exits, but only in the release build.
Issue Description:
Behavior:

When I launch the application (from the IDE), it starts a cmd window,
and both the application and the cmd window stay open independently.
After compiling the application, installing it, and running the
release build, the cmd window closes automatically right after the
application exits.

What I've Tried:
All those have been thoroughly explored using ChatGPT and the www

Using the start command to launch cmd.
Executing PowerShell scripts to start the process detached.
Utilizing JNA (Java Native Access) to manage process handling.

Observations:

In all cases, the cmd window closes when the application terminates
in the release build.
The issue does not occur when running the app directly from the IDE.

Development Environment:

Kotlin Version: 1.8.0
Compose plugin Version: 1.6.2
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (works as expected when running from IDE)
Operating System: Windows 10

Example:
fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "cmd").start()
        exitApplication()
    }
}

Thank you very much!

Can you create a small sample program that exhibits the same behavior that others could compile and use to re-create the problem?  Without any of code to look its difficult to say what the prob might be.  It would just be speculation.  Plus, it might help you narrow down what the problem might be.

Also, at first glance my take was that this is expected behavior.  On Windows when a parent terminates, the OS terminates all the child processes.  Where you mention "detached" above, i think that refers to running detached from the parent's console, not detached from the parent.

Indeed after some research, it seems that detaching a process from its parent is a no-go. The actual goal of this task is to launch app updates, which require the app to be shut down.

I've tried creating a PowerShell, and from it start another PowerShell, I check its parent which is the first one, then I delete the first one and the parent of the second is still the one closed. But both are also attached to "conhost".

Solution: It's specific to my case, I have a service installed with the application that checks every second if the latest update has been downloaded in the Appdata/MyApp/tmp folder.
Still, if anybody knows a way for this issue I'm inquisitive.

I think there are a whole bunch of Windows APIs/subsystems for doing this kind of think both inside and outside the app store.  It may be more than you want to bite off though.  https://winsparkle.org/ too
